# AngularJs call method in template directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have following directive that renders a number value like *3* as *3.xxx*
depending on argument `decimals`

```
 app.directive("myValue", () => {
        return {
            template: '{{value.toFixed(decimals)}}',
            scope: {
                'value': '=myValue',
                'decimals': '=myValueDecimals'
            },
            link: function () {
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I want to include handling of *special* values like `undefined`,`NAN` etc.
I already have a function that should replace *value.toFixed(decimals)*
but I cannot figure out how to call a function directly in the directive.

**Update**: the view value is being changed dynamically so it should be refreshed whenever the value changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `viewValue` in the directive's scope and assign handled value to it. For typescript you might want to do something like this:

```js
interface IValueScope extends IScope {
    viewValue:number;
}

 app.directive("myValue", () => {
        return {
            template: '{{viewValue}}',
            scope: {
                'value': '=myValue',
                'decimals': '=myValueDecimals',
   
            },
            link: function ($scope:IValueScope) {
            $scope.viewValue = $scope.value == null || Number.isNaN($scope.value)
                ? 0 
                : $scope.value.toFixed($scope.decimals);
            }
        }
    });
```

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.component('home', {
  template: '<span><button ng-click="$ctrl.inc()">Inc</button> <data-val data-my-value="$ctrl.v" data-my-value-decimals="2" ></my-value> </span>',
  controller: function() {
    this.v = 1;
    this.inc = () => this.v += 1;
  }

});

app.directive("val", () => {
  return {
    template: '{{viewValue}}',
    scope: {
      'value': '<myValue',
      'decimals': '<myValueDecimals',
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      const newValue = (v) => v == null || Number.isNaN(v) ?
        0 :
        v.toFixed($scope.decimals)

      $scope.viewValue = newValue($scope.value);

      const cleanup = $scope.$watch('value', (value) => {
        $scope.viewValue = newValue(value)
      });
      $scope.$on('$destroy', () => cleanup());
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <home></home>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something similar but would also end up with something like this: Build:Property 'viewValue' does not exist on type 'IScope'

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Try this one, if it will not work (this depends on the tsc version you are using, I will provide a solution with casting. But this looks cleaner.

Comment: Thx but IValueScope does not exist. I'll go with any!

Comment: You need to declare ```IValueScope``` yourself on top of the directive. But with any it also will work

Comment: okay fine now it works - thx! but with this approach the view does not get updated when value changes. with the first approched this worked!

Comment: Sad to say, but you need to watch values manually. Example provded